# How to start mongoDB with replicaSet by config file on Ubuntu 14.04.4

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, replication, mongodb-replica-set

Hi I've configured MongoDB with a replicaSet. If i run the command:

```
sudo mongod --replSet "rs0"
```

Everything works and the 3 replicas work, but if i run the command:

```
sudo mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

It doesn't work, the shell doesn't display anything and if i check the process running mongod is not running with the replica set.

This is my mongod.conf:

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
 dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
 journal:
  enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
 systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
 port: 27017
 #  bindIp: 127.0.0.1


#processManagement:

#security:

#operationProfiling:

replication:
    replSetName: "rs0"
```

and this is the log file:

```
2016-04-28T15:34:30.079+0000 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2016-04-28T15:34:30.097+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=30634 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=db-test01
2016-04-28T15:34:30.097+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.5
2016-04-28T15:34:30.097+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 34e65e5383f7ea1726332cb175b73077ec4a1b02
2016-04-28T15:34:30.097+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
2016-04-28T15:34:30.097+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-04-28T15:34:30.097+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-04-28T15:34:30.097+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-04-28T15:34:30.097+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1404
2016-04-28T15:34:30.097+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-04-28T15:34:30.097+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-04-28T15:34:30.097+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { port: 27017 }, replication: { replSetName: "res0" }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
2016-04-28T15:34:30.168+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /var/lib/mongodb created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2016-04-28T15:34:30.168+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=1G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2016-04-28T15:34:30.907+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-04-28T15:34:30.908+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Insecure configuration, access control is not enabled and no --bind_ip has been specified.
2016-04-28T15:34:30.908+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted,
2016-04-28T15:34:30.908+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          and the server listens on all available network interfaces.
2016-04-28T15:34:30.908+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended.
2016-04-28T15:34:30.908+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-04-28T15:34:30.908+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-04-28T15:34:30.908+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2016-04-28T15:34:30.908+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-04-28T15:34:30.908+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-04-28T15:34:30.908+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-04-28T15:34:30.908+0000 I REPL     [initandlisten] Did not find local voted for document at startup;  NoMatchingDocument: Did not find replica set lastVote document in local.replset.election
2016-04-28T15:34:30.909+0000 I REPL     [initandlisten] Did not find local replica set configuration document at startup;  NoMatchingDocument: Did not find replica set configuration document in local.system.replset
2016-04-28T15:34:30.909+0000 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/var/lib/mongodb/diagnostic.data'
2016-04-28T15:34:30.909+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2016-04-28T15:34:30.909+0000 I NETWORK  [HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Starting hostname canonicalization worker
```

Comment: what is there in /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

Comment: @titogeo I've edited the question.

Comment: you first started with rs0 then with res0. Is that causing issue? can you change  in .conf and see once.

Comment: @titogeo Thanks this was an error, but it doesn't work. The log file is the same with "rs0"

Comment: Not sure what the issue in, if data in not important wipe the data folders and try restarting

Comment: your `local` database kept replSetName as 'rs0' you first initiated. However in your config you changed it to 'res0' which is inconsistent.